# Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS ubuntu tty1

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, login

I just downloaded Ubuntu on VirtualBox and I installed it and after the installation it rebooted and then locked in a black screen and asks for ubuntu login and password.
How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is you host system: Win XP, Win 7, Ubuntu?.  Have you downloaded the server version of Ubuntu?  The server version has no Gui.  What happens when you enter your user name and password?

Answer (score 0):

You did provide the username and password, name for your computer, etc. details during the installation, didn't you? The username and password appear to be what you need..

I'm gonna need further info, is this window a terminal (shell, CLI) or a window as in X-Window (GUI)?

P.S. I strongly recommend reinstalling Ubuntu in case the installation was not successful. There may be some important files missing, and given how most of the info is stored as files in Ubuntu, that may pose a big problem to the integrity of your installation..